# Sklearn Scaler output behavior

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-processing

I have a situation where I want to apply sklearn's StandardScaler object to one column of my dataframe. The code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.DataFrame([(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5)], columns=['a','b','c'])
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(df['c'].values.reshape(-1,1))
df['d'] = df['c'].apply(scaler.transform)
df
```

When I scale column c and output the result into column d, the values in d looks like `[[-1.224744871391589]]`, with shape `(1,1)`

I would have expected the output value to be a numerical value, not a list as seen above.  I can of course get around it by doing something along the lines of `df['d'] = df['d'].apply(lambda x: x[0][0])`, but if not necessary, I want to avoid such additional complications.

Am I using the scaler object incorrectly or is this the only way to work around it?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `apply()` gives single values of that column as input to scaler. `scaler.transform()` has a output shape of `[n_samples,n_columns]`. So its returning correctly as [1,1] array. So no workaround here. Please see last line of @KRKirov answer to get the correct way of transforming a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom is to instantiate the trasformer/estimator first and then to fit and transform. Here is what the output is with a couple of minor changes:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.DataFrame([(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5)], columns=['a','b','c'])

scaler = StandardScaler()

scaler.fit(df['c'].values.reshape(-1,1))

df['d'] = scaler.transform(df['c'].values.reshape(-1,1))
df

Out[84]: 
   a  b  c         d
0  1  2  3 -1.224745
1  2  3  4  0.000000
2  3  4  5  1.224745
```

Comment: This error is not related to this. We can very well do what the OP has done because `fit()` returns the self object. The error here is how pandas gives the input to scaler and how scaler gives output.

Comment: I am not claiming the error is due to the StandardScaler not being instantiated separately. Just sharing good practice. The change comes in the following two command lines. As you can see my output is different from that of Calpis.

Comment: I notice that. He is also getting the same output, just a singleton array for each value. I was talking only about this line: `scaler = StandardScaler().fit(df['c'].values.reshape(-1,1))`

Comment: I like the comment you have made above. It is very useful explaining that the problem comes from the use of apply.